# C# printer prints just a quarter of the submitted picture

Tags: c#, image, printing

Greetings,

i have a little application which should be able to print single jpeg files to a network printer. Now the printing itself works but the problem is that the printer prints just the upper left quarter of the picture, no matter which picture i use. Typically the picture is 1800x1200 px and in jpeg format.

The code im using to print is the following:

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
    doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "KONICA MINOLTA C250/C250P PCL";
    doc.PrintPage += this.Doc_PrintPage;
    if(doc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        doc.Print();
}


private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage((System.Drawing.Image)ShowImg(bild.ToolTip),x, y);
}
```

The ShowImg() function just returns a Bitmap with the picture from a network drive.
Does anyone know why this strange behaviour happens?

Thanks in advance
xen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that i was using 300dpi for my jpeg where the printer just supported 90dpi. Silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

What are MarginBounds.Height/Width?
Take a look at image dimensions too...

```
private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
    var img = (System.Drawing.Image)ShowImg(bild.ToolTip);

    Debug.Print("img: {0}x{1}", img.Width, img.Height);    
    Debug.Print("margins: {0}x{1}", e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height);    

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img,x, y);
}
```

I hope you'll see the difference between their dimensions.